# In Unity, how can I change the launcher so that it doesn't automatically scroll to the top?

Tags: unity, launcher, scrolling

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 installed on my tablet and its difficult to use because the launcher always scrolls to the top.  I want to set it up so that it simply doesn't automatically scroll at all, what so ever.  I only want it to scroll when I click and drag it, and I want it to stay exactly where it's at afterwards.

I am using Unity.  I have Ubuntu Tweak installed and I have Compiz installed.  Not sure if either of these can pull this off.

Is this possible?